# modulenot found 'keras.layer.embeddings' i dont have any idea how to fix this even though i installed keras properly

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis, keras-layer

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from wordcloud import WordCloud

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag


from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Lambda
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, SimpleRNN, GRU
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from collections import defaultdict
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution1D
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
```

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 37
 35 from keras.models import Sequential
 36 from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Lambda
---> 37 from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
 38 from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, SimpleRNN, GRU
 39 from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.embeddings'
```

these error keep coming i dont know how to fix this
Module not fount 'keras.layers.embeddind'
and i tried every thing on internet cant fix this later issue

Comment: just do from keras.layers import Embedding, there is no need to imports from internal keras modules.

Answer (score 7):

`keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding` has been moved to `keras.layers.Embedding`. You can update your code as follows:

```py
from keras.layers import Embedding
```